# Converting C# event implementation to VB.NET

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net, gridview, c#-to-vb.net

I am trying to use some C# code that expands on the GridView functionality in a VB.NET project. The code I'm using is from [here](http://www.agrinei.com/gridviewhelper/gridviewhelper_en.htm).

In the C# code there is an event definition for GroupHeader:

```cs
/// <summary>
/// Event triggered after a row for group header be inserted
/// </summary>
public event GroupEvent GroupHeader;
```

This is expanded by example on the above web site:

```cs
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    GridViewHelper helper = new GridViewHelper(this.GridView1);
    helper.RegisterGroup("ShipRegion", true, true);
    helper.RegisterGroup("ShipName", true, true);
    helper.GroupHeader += new GroupEvent(helper_GroupHeader);
    helper.ApplyGroupSort();
}

private void helper_GroupHeader(string groupName, object[] values, GridViewRow row)
{
    if (groupName == "ShipRegion")
    {
        row.BackColor = Color.LightGray;
        row.Cells[0].Text = "&nbsp;&nbsp;" + row.Cells[0].Text;
    }
    else if (groupName == "ShipName")
    {
        row.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(236, 236, 236);
        row.Cells[0].Text = "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;" + row.Cells[0].Text;
    }
}
```

My question is, how do I convert this code to VB.NET?

I have converted the event implementation like so:

```vb
Private Sub helper_GroupHeader(ByVal groupName As String, ByVal values As Object(), ByVal row As GridViewRow)
    Try
        If groupName = "ITEM#" Then
            row.BackColor = Color.LightBlue
            row.Cells(0).Text = "&nbsp;&nbsp;" & row.Cells(0).Text
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try
End Sub
```

How can I then call (raise?) this event with VB.NET?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're  looking for [`AddHandler`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7taxzxka%28v=vs.100%29.aspx):

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Dim helper As New GridViewHelper(Me.GridView1)
    helper.RegisterGroup("ShipRegion", True, True)
    helper.RegisterGroup("ShipName", True, True)
    AddHandler helper.GroupHeader, AddressOf helper_GroupHeader
    helper.ApplyGroupSort()
End Sub
```

I assume that the event is implicitely raised from `GridViewHelper`.

Answer (score 1):

You would subscribe to the event using [`AddHandler`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6yyk8z93%28VS.90%29.aspx):

```
AddHandler GroupHeader, AddressOf helper_GroupHeader
```

And raise the event using [`RaiseEvent`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fwd3bwed%28VS.90%29.aspx):

```
RaiseEvent GroupHeader()
```